# How to use OR in this regex to get 2 or 3 numbers before a specific character?

Tags: php, regex

My question is how do I modify the following regex to get the numbers from this string `160bhp,` BUT also the numbers from the `90bhp,` string?

For now, it takes only the 3 numbers and ignores the 2. I am trying with | without luck.

```
preg_match_all('/(\d{3})bhp\b,/', $str2b, $bhps);
```

Answer (score 1):

Am guessing you may want to generalise this to match one or more digits before the bhp (with no upper limit)? If that's the case, use this:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+)bhp\b,/', $str2b, $bhps);
```

Taking this a bit further, would zero or more whitespace characters be allowed between, e.g. "200 bhp"? If so, use this:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+)\s*bhp\b,/', $str2b, $bhps);
```

And finally, does it need to be case insensitive, e.g. to allow 300BHP? If so, put an `i` after the final slash:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+)\s*bhp\b,/i', $str2b, $bhps);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/(\d{2,3})bhp\b,/', $str2b, $bhps);
```

> There's an additional quantifier that allows you to specify how many times a token can be repeated. The syntax is {min,max}, where min is zero or a positive integer number indicating the minimum number of matches, and max is an integer equal to or greater than min indicating the maximum number of matches. If the comma is present but max is omitted, the maximum number of matches is infinite.
>
> Source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Bt if you want it to match also `1bhp` and `160000bhp` for example, use this instead:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+)bhp\b,/', $str2b, $bhps);
```

Which will capture any number of digits on the left of `bhp`

Answer (score 0):

You simply change the value between the brackets to be `{2,3}`.

```
preg_match_all('/(\d{2,3})bhp\b,/', $str2b, $bhps);
```

This basically provides a minimum/maximum number of the preceding character definition that is to be matched.

Answer (score 0):

`\d{3}` is saying there needs to be exactly 3 digits. Changing the `{3}` to `*` should solve the problem and allow you to retrieve any number of consecutive digits before the `bhp`.

```
preg_match_all('/(\d*)bhp\b,/', $str2b, $bhps);
```

[regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) is an excellent online regex tester.